# MIPS: How do parse out digits of a number? Basic question but yet hard

Tags: assembly, mips

I am currently learing MIPS for a class and wrote the below sample code.

```
# UNTITLED PROGRAM

.data   # Data declaration section

.text

       main:      # Start of code section

               li $t1, 72
           move $a0, $t1
           li $v0,1

       exit:
              li $v0, 10
              syscall

# END OF PROGRAM
```

As shown the value of '72' is stored in register $t1.  Now, how do I parse out the '7' and '2' out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by 10, the modulo is your next digit, repeat until the result of division is 0. This assuming you're not working with floating point numbers.

Comment: Wow, it was that easy!  I will see if there is some optimization I can do such as shifting the bits.  I'm off to a good start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a mips expert... but:

72 / F = 7   "7"

7 * F = 70

72 - 70 = 2   "2"

You can apply this logic using F * (number of total digits - 1) to get each individual digit.

-r

Comment: I am not using floating point numbers so I am unsure what is being said here.  I will have to look at the MIPS documenation to see what "F" actually is.  I think it stands for floatin point.